# Finding a two-digit number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The sum of the digits of a two-digit number is $9$. When we intrchange the digits,it is found that the resulting new number is greater than the original number by $27$. What is two digit number?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: Good answer by Shabbeh but you could do this by brute force method :)

Answer (score 3):

$$\overline{ab}-\overline{ba}=27$$

$$(10a+b)-(10b+a)=27$$

$$a-b=3$$

and we know that :

$$a+b=9$$

so $a=6$ and $b=3$

Answer (score 1):

Let the two digits be $x$ and $9-x$. By condition, the reversed no. will be$10(9-x)+x$ and this  is 27 more than the previous no. So, $$
$$
$10(9-x)+x=27+(9-x)+10x \implies 90-9x=36+9x \implies 18x=54 \implies x=3,$ so that the other no. is $9-x=9-3=6.$ Got it ???